# VBA Folder Renaming

Tags: vba, rename, directory

I am looking to use VBA to rename a set of folders. The purpose is to remove special characters from the folder names such as - : ; /, etc. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub File_renaming2()
Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject, myObj As Object, mySource As Object, Folder As Variant
Set mySource = myObj.GetFolder("C:\Users\John.Doe\Desktop\ABC\VBA Test folder")

For Each Folder In mySource.Folder
    Folder.Name.Replace What:="-", Replacement:=" " 'replace - with space
    Folder.Name.Replace What:=":", Replacement:=" " 'replace : with space
    Folder.Name.Replace What:=";", Replacement:=" " 'replace ; with space
    Folder.Name.Replace What:="/", Replacement:=" " 'replace / with space

    Next Folder

End Sub
```

I am new to VBA and made the code off of the solutions to similar questions online, but this appears to give me

> run-time error '91'- Object variable or With block variable not set.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Using `Option Explicit` always helps identify problems.  Also, it's not enough to declare an object variable: it remains as `Nothing` until you actually create it.

Comment: I'm not sure but you might need to start from the children folder to the parent. If you change the parent name when you go and try to change the child, It's not going to find the path...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**edited**: after user feedback

you have to set all object variables before using them

and you have to be consistent with the name you chose for them... (`myObj` shoudl be `objFSO`)

as per following code

```
Option Explicit

Sub File_renaming2()
    Dim objFSO As FileSystemObject, myObj As Object, mySource As Object, Folder As Variant
    Dim newName As String

    Set objFSO = New FileSystemObject
    Set mySource = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\John.Doe\Desktop\ABC\VBA Test folder")

    For Each Folder In mySource.SubFolders
        newName = Folder.name
        newName = Replace(newName, "-", " ")  'replace - with space
        newName = Replace(newName, ":", " ")  'replace : with space
        newName = Replace(newName, ";", " ")  'replace ; with space
        newName = Replace(newName, "/", " ")  'replace / with space
        If Folder.name <> newName Then Folder.name = newName ' assign new name. the check is to (possibly) ensure you're not processing the same folder twice
    Next Folder
End Sub
```

since it seems FSO would not allow to change twice the name of the same folder in the same "session".

Comment: Hello, revisiting this code, I am getting error 58 that the file already exists when it comes to:         If Folder.name <> newName Then Folder.name = newName

Comment: What references are you using?

Comment: I used “Microsoft Scripting Runtime”